# Android: gradle and java code linking

Tags: java, android

Say I have 2 sets of variables.One meant for Staging while the other is for production.Is it to make the java code return the different sets based on a global variable set in gradle or any other place I can set such a variable.

I am not looking for build flavours and neither am I looking at Global java class to keep track of this.
Is something like this possible using the build environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Define variable in `build.gradle` file

   ```
   buildTypes {
       staging {
           buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_STAGING", "true"
       }

       release {
           buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_STAGING", "false"
       }
   }
   ```
2. Use it in your code

   ```
   if (BuildConfig.IS_STAGING) {
       // variables for staging
   } else {
       // variables for release
   }
   ```

**P.S.:** Using **flavors** and resource folders for that is more correct and clean.

Answer (score 0):

use asset directory in res put there property text file with whatever data you want and read from app. use gradle ant.propertyfile  to  modify properties 
`ant.propertyfile(
        file: "res/asset/myfile.properties") {
        entry( key: "propertyName", value: "propertyValue")
        entry( key: "anotherProperty", operation: "del")
    }`